# @types/mssql - cannot find connection pool type defs even though TS is looking in the right place

Tags: typescript, typescript-types

I am using the latest versions of the `mssql` package and the `@types/mssql` package, and my typeRoots directory seems to be correctly set, but I keep getting these errors when trying to compile the TypeScript code:

```
error TS2339: Property 'connect' does not exist on type 'typeof "c:/Users/blahblahblah/node_modules/@types/mssql/index"'.
error TS2339: Property 'query' does not exist on type 'typeof "C:/Users/blahblahblah/node_modules/@types/mssql/index"'
```

The tsconfig seems to be ok, so not sure what's going on. Any ideas?

I can always just remove the @types library, but trying to keep with best practices here.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** Here is some sample code, it's just a straightforward SQL Server connection example:

```
import * as sql from 'mssql'

// test connection to SQL server using node-mssql
const connectToSqlServer = (async (): Promise<void> => {
  try {
    const pool = await sql.connect(config)
    const result = await sql.query`select * from mock_people`
    console.dir(result)
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err)
  }
})()
```

both `connect` and `query` have squiggles under them. When I hover over `sql`, it just shows me the `import sql` rather than the type, but as you can see from the error, TypeScript is looking in the right place for the type def.

Comment: If you can add some sample code on the line where you're calling `query` or `connect` it would be helpful. It doesn't appear to be a configuration issue

Comment: @charmeleon, thanks for taking a look. Added sample code above. Sorry, should have included that from the get go. It really seems like everything is right, so not sure if this is just an issue with they type defs themselves?  [Here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/d337ba060d6149d4fe3af2458b423b96f5eef0cb/types/mssql/index.d.ts#L186) is where connect and query are defined.

Answer (score 5):

You're trying to use `sql.connect` directly but it looks like you should be using `sql.ConnectionPool.connect`: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/mssql/index.d.ts#L193

So your code should look more like this (I don't have a `mssql` connection handy so this is untested):

```
const connectToSqlServer = (async (): Promise<void> => {
  try {
    const pool = new sql.ConnectionPool(config);
    pool.connect().then(() => {
        const request = new sql.Request(pool);
        const result = await request.query(`select * from mock_people`);
        console.dir(result);
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err)
  }
})()
```

Comment: that's what the type defs seem to imply, right? However, that's definitely not the case, unless they've completely forgotten to update their docs which I think is unlikely. Unless I totally don't understand how the type def files work... but it looks like its expecting directly exposed `connect` and `query` defs on the main object, but they of course, don't exist. So could this really be a mistake with the docs? Or a mistake with the way versioning lines up? If so, I'll open an issue on the repo, but with nearly 2K open issues, I'm guessing this won't be high priority.

Comment: Either way, I'll try this, but it seems odd that it defies every example I've seen of using this library. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: So it's possible that without TypeScript you can use the library in the way you posted originally, but the `@types/mssql` library is missing types and doesn't reflect that, so the TypeScript compiler complains even though the underlying native JavaScript would've worked anyway. One other thing you could try is compiling with `--allowJs` to get around any missing types

Comment: yeah, I have `"noImplicitAny": false` set in my `.tsconfig` (and `allowJs`) so it will compile without the @types lib, it's just annoying that I can't get it to work properly. Looks like I oughta open an issue on DefinitelyTyped and see how that goes. Thanks for looking into it though!

Comment: I'm facing exactly the same issue, so there's no type definition for sql.connect(), right?

Comment: yeah you should avoid leaving a SQL connection open

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is augment the module in TypeScript. Add `mssql.d.ts`

```
import sql from 'mssql'

declare module 'mssql' {
  function connect(connectionString: string): Promise<void>
  const query: sql.ConnectionPool['query']
  const close: sql.ConnectionPool['close']
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think the above solution is right, but one little correction...

```
const connectToSqlServer = (async (): Promise<void> => {
  try {
    const pool = new sql.ConnectionPool('mssql://sa:myPassw0rd@192.168.1.10/BAMSDB')
    pool.connect().then(async () => {
      const request = new sql.Request(pool)
      const result = await request.query(`select * from mock_people`)
      console.dir(result)
    })
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err)
  }
})()
```